# List the name and job of staff who have the same job as JONES, but do not display the JONES record

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query so far, struggling with how not to display the JONES record though...

SELECT SNAME, JOB FROM STAFF
WHERE JOB IN (SELECT JOB FROM STAFF WHERE SNAME = 'JONES');

Result...

SNAME      JOB

---

JONES      MANAGER
HAYAT      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER

Comment: .. `AND sname != 'JONES'`

Comment: If you know how to select `JONES` only, I presume you should know how to exclude them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.SNAME, s.JOB
FROM staff s
LEFT JOIN staff b ON s.JOB = b.JOB 
WHERE b.SNAME = 'JONES' AND s.SNAME != 'JONES'
```

Comment: This is not a `LEFT JOIN` as the `WHERE` filter converts it from a `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Add another filter to exclude the `JONES` row(s):

```sql
SELECT SNAME,
       JOB
FROM   STAFF
WHERE  JOB IN (SELECT JOB FROM STAFF WHERE SNAME = 'JONES')
AND    sname != 'JONES';
```

or, without querying the table twice:

```sql
SELECT sname,
       job
FROM   (
  SELECT sname,
         job,
         COUNT(CASE sname WHEN 'JONES' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY job)
           AS num_jones
  FROM   staff
)
WHERE  num_jones > 0
AND    sname != 'JONES';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE staff (sname, job) AS
SELECT 'JONES', 'MANAGER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'HAYAT', 'MANAGER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CLARK', 'MANAGER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'CEO'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BERYL', 'CTO'     FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

| SNAME | JOB |
| --- | --- |
| HAYAT | MANAGER |
| CLARK | MANAGER |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cx1ylGra)

Comment: Thank you, that has helped my understanding.